# roo and paperclip in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, roo-gem

I am working on a rails app and I am using paperclip to upload files
 and I would like to open the file for processing with roo. But the following code is not working for me.                                                                                                 xls = Roo::Excel.new(@student.file.path)

Any suggestios?

Comment: what it returns? an error? please show it

Comment: It's hard to determine where your problem lies with the limited amount of information you provided. Can you please provide the model code where you define the paperclip attachment, the Gemfile showing the relevant gems, and any errors associated with the above code snippet you provided?